# Override toString method for all List classes in application

Tags: java, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

In my Spring boot application I have many classes which have Lists of some objects. And those Lists could be really big. Not a big deal but when it comes to logging  it become to be a problem.
When logging such class with big list output from List.toString() method clutters the logs.
    I am wondering is there a way to override somehow all List.toString() methods in application easily?
    Aspects come to my mind, but not all of those classes are beans in Spring.
    Of cause I could override toString() method in every single class which has such big List, but may be more elegant solution exists?

Comment: Why you log entire list!!!!?

Comment: @Null Actually I don't need it. But I need to log outer classes which contains such Lists. And I wanted to get rid of entire list logging but in some smart way.

Comment: Actually you should either refactor the applications to log the right thing or configure logging so as to limit the length of what gets logged via filters or formatters. But for what it is worth, you could use AOP in order to do what you want. If you want to affect non-Spring components, you need to shift up one gear AOP-wise, though, and use AspectJ instead of Spring AOP. Please let me know if you really want to do that just for logging and if so, edit your question in order to contain some code and also info about logging framework used, so my answer is a bit closer to your reality.